# after trimming a string in php the string length is same is showing

Tags: string, variadic-functions, trim

```
?php
$a=" just wait ";
echo "Before trimming string length=".strlen($a)."<br>";
echo trim($a)."<br>";
echo "After trimming string length=".strlen($a);
?>
```

1. String length is same after trim a string. please help to me.
2. I tried number of times but not getting the correct output

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the value of `$a` when you trim it. See below

```
<?php
    $a=" just wait ";
    echo "Before trimming string length=".strlen($a)."<br>";
    $a = trim($a)."<br>";
    echo "After trimming string length=".strlen($a);
?>
```